# Form input of cents that automatically converts to dollars as they type

Tags: javascript, forms, input, jscript

Is there a way to add a jscript code to place on a number input field that converts the numbers into dollars and cents as they type?

I want to use the TEL input on a dollar field to make it easier for people on a phone to input numbers. The problem is there is no decimal point on the Tel input pad.

What I want to do is automatically convert this into dollars and cents as they type.

displaying 0.00 initially and as they type 1234 for example the display changes to 0.01 0.12 1.23 12.34 and so on?

I hope someone has a suggestion as I have looked through the internet and found one that adds .00 at the end, but if I have to input a cent value this does not help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/ I think this is what you want

Comment: You can attach a keyUp event listener to the input element and have it divide the value by 100 (or set it to 0.00), then set it again.

This feels like a potential misuse of the `tel` input type, though, that may actually present accessibility problems to some users. If their phone's browser insists it must be a telephone number (because that's what [`tel` is for](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.tel.html)), it might decide not to play nicely with the decimal point, for example.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `tel` input type for anything but telephone numbers. The `number` input type works fine on mobile and should only display a number keyboard layout.